# how to convert Map<Integer, List> to List

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

I have a Map `Map<Integer, List>` with key, values. I need to convert this into List and pass it to the calling function. Once I have the list i need to convert this back to `Map<Integer, List>`

The reason I am converting the map to list is because i need to create webservice for this method. As I cannot expose the Map to webservice I need to convert this to list.

How to achieve this..?

Comment: You want to convert it to a `list` of what?

Comment: Once you decide how that new list is going to look, you'll have easier time answering your question by yourself.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention it is List<String>

Comment: Is working only with List, not with Map, hard to mantain or refactor? This convertion could cause a performance glitch. The generic List parameterized in Map<Integer, List> is a List<String>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i read you are trying to pass map via list (as your service limitation).

In case you don't find any better solution, you can always use two lists. One for keys and one for values.

(but you are risking breaking map consistency with this approach).

Answer (score 2):

A map has two functions called `keySet()` and `values()`. They return the keys and values of the map respectively. The keyes are returned as a `Set` and the values as a `Collection`.

You can create a list from either of these.

Here is an example:

```
Map<Integer, List> map = // map creation;
List<Integer> keyList = new ArrayList<Integer>(map.keySet());
List<List> valueList = new ArrayList<List>(map.values());
```

Comment: List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>(layoutMap.values()); i tried this but there is no constructor defined. Is it safe to use the raw type array list

Comment: WARNING: This solution is broken, because there is no guarantee that the keyList and the valueList obtain this way have the same order. It may work for some map implementation and associate values with the wrong key for other map implementations.

Comment: @user1103504 The list needs to be List<List<String>>

Comment: @SamuelRossille I did not see any requirement pointing to the ordering of the elements. What I meant was that he could use either one. If he needs both keys and elements then entrySet() is probably preferred.

Comment: @LudwigMagnusson If OP want to output a map, then the relation between keys and values has it's importance, and it you output two lists, what can preserve this relation apart from having the same order ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class with two attributes (Integer, List) and create a List with one object by key.

Also, you can use:

```
new ArrayList(Map.entrySet());
```

and convert the resulting set to a list.

Answer (score 0):

To get the values (Strings):

```
List<List<String>> listVals = new ArrayList<List<String>>(map.values());
```

To get the keys:

```
List<Integer> listKeys = new ArrayList<Integer>(map.keySet());
```

Comment: Sorry, but nothing guarantees that keys and values will be retrieved in the same order.

Comment: Well, if you create two lists and they are not in the same order relatively to an iteration over the entrySet, which is not specified by the map interface, you are loosing the relation between the keys and the value => the information hold by the map is lost

Comment: I understood that and I'm well aware of it, but deducing from OP's question, it seems that he is only interested in map values. 
Thank you for your feedback, nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

A map contains key value pair but list does not contains key value pair. So u can create a bean class to set key and values and then create list which contains objects of the bean class.